# PDFBox Change Content Encoding

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

How can I change the content text encoding using the pdfbox? Currently, I have a PDF with a lot of contents inside and the content is somehow encoded. Example shown as below

[pdfcontent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCXZT.png)

I would like to change the text encoding to something similar to the one below

[expected_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfP6l.png)

I am quite new to pdfbox and would like to get some insight.

Comment: It's encoded because the font is a subset (the + in the name, and see also firstchar lastchar in the first screenshot). I suspect you have a completely different problem, but whatever it is, changing the encoding isn't the solution.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Is it possible to decode the content and encode to ASCII ? i understand that i need to change the resources font also.

Comment: I've leave this to somebody else. It sounds like a lot of work and pain, the font would have to be replaced and each of these strings too. And then, surprise, you'll encounter a case where a string that has a non ASCII character.

Comment: *"Is it possible to decode the content and encode to ASCII ?"* - from what you show in that example screen shot it is not even clear that the drawn glyphs represent characters from the ASCII character set. So while it certainly *is* possible to re-encode the content stream and the font to have bytes from the ASCII character range in the arguments of the text drawing instructions, it is not clear that they are what you want.